# Como personalizar a página de erro do Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Quando ocorre  um erro no `Laravel 4`, estando com a configuração do `app.debug` igual a `false`, a seguinte página é retornada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso, tanto para erros `500` quanto para `404`, essa página é exibida.

Existe alguma maneira de alterar a página que é exibida, quando ocorre apenas o erro 400?

Existe uma maneira de definir uma `view` específica para cada tipo de erro com determinado código de resposta http?

Exemplo, quero definir uma página de erro para status `404` e outra para `500`. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu procurei os "resources" mas não achei, no entanto conforme este link https://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-quick-tip-custom-error-pages você pode fazer assim:

```
App::error(function($exception, $code)
{
    $error = array( 'error' => $exception->getMessage());
    switch ($code)
    {
        case 403:
            return Response::view('errors.403', $error, 403);

        case 404:
            return Response::view('errors.404', $error, 404);

        case 500:
            return Response::view('errors.500', $error, 500);

        default:
            return Response::view('errors.default', $error, $code);
    }
});
```

Toda requisição onde a resposta está relacionado a um erro de `http`, o `Laravel` utiliza esse método `App::error` para verificar se você fez alguma personalização para determinado erro. A forma que isso é feito é verificando se existe alguma coisa sendo retornada pela closure passada como argumento de `App::error`. Caso retorne `null` ou `none` (return vazio), o Laravel usará o erro padrão (que é o whoops!).

Lembrando que, quando você configura a página de erro, a chamada de `App::abort()` também é afetada. Ou seja, se fizer isso...

```
return App::abort('Acesso não autorizado', 403);
```

... Não será mais chamado o erro `whoops!`, e sim o que você definiu. Nesse caso, o valor dos argumentos `$code` e `$exception->getMessage()` serão os valores passados para `App::abort()`;

Comment: É isso mesmo. Eu já implementei aqui no sistema. Se você quiser ignorar algum erro, na verdade é só não retornar nada, que o Laravel usa o erro padrão.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters fiquei confuso sobre seu comentário, ignorar erro e erro padrão.

Comment: Se você quiser ignorar um código http específico de erro, é só retornar null. Isso que quis dizer.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters obrigado pelo detalhamento, eu não tinha ido tão a fundo :)

Comment: eu sou um fuçador do Laravel.